Which Talmud published by Rabbinical Scholars is free of censorship?
I have read about the Munich Manuscript being censored because some parts were erased, I have also read of the Talmud surviving in Egypt where papyrus and parchment doesn't decay from humidity... But modern versions of the Talmud, are they censored in any way? I'm an atheist that loves Israel, my wish is for them to have a faithful Talmud because it's unfair that Muslims have their hadiths and Qurans perfectly preserved, but Jewish holy books were cut down and censored by fascist "Christian" extremists during the Middle Ages.

Much appreciated, we do want all our Torah back (including entire missing tractates) but we have given up for now until Moshiach comes :) Although people of Harel13's ilk are doing their best to recover whatever they can.

The Munich Codex is relatively free of censorship. On the contrary, although the Vilna edition was heavily censored, it was a high quality edition compared to its contemporaries, which gained acclaim among Torah scholars. Many later editions were based on the Vilna Shas, and only in recent years there was an intent to reinsert the erased passages. Although these omissions are fascinating from a scientific perspective, they don't really matter when studying Gemara. Moreover, since the Talmud is a compendium of oral teachings, there's no definitive edition, and the manuscripts slightly differ.

@Kazibácsi what does that mean "they don't really matter"? Evidently they were put in the Gemara in the first place because they hold importance according to the creators of the Talmud.

@Harel13 Honestly, how much do the stories bashing Yoschke add to your understanding of complex concepts in the gemara? We're both interested in Jewish history, and these are priceless socio-cultural sources for people like us, but I don't really think they make much difference for an average yeshivah student. I assume חז"ל wanted to warn us about the dangers of Christianity, but I think 1500 years of European history made their point fairly evident.

To the OP, the hadiths and Quran haven't been perfectly preserved. There are endless disagreements on which hadiths are original and there are several different versions of the Quran. Not to mention the early Islamic attempts at suppressing variant textual traditions by gathering up Qurans and destroying them.

@Kazibácsi IMO, your starting point is "I'm used to the gemara we have now, so who needs the original text?" but really you have no idea what you might have gained from having the pure uncensored version throughout the ages with many sages carefully analyzing and explaining the relevancy and importance of these passages along with all other passages.

@Harel13 My point is that I'm fascinated with such details due to my personal taste, and I was astonished when during a daf yomi shiur of Sanhedrin someone pulled out a small booklet from his bag and said that now listen carefully, because these parts were not printed in the gemarot in front of you. Yet I also understand that I represent a small minority, and I dare to say that I understand why. [I'm happy to talk about the matter, but I suppose it belongs to the chat.]

They say the Venice edition was less-censored too, if I'm not mistaken; and certainly anything from Islamic lands would have no problem with material critical of early Christianity. But that's for academics. If the layman wants to read an uncensored Talmud today, as linked in the other question, several recent printings have done that research for you and restored the material.
